# laravel pagination -which value has the second param

Tags: laravel, pagination

Just a shorty:

For what is the second parameter ['*']
in:

```
return $ContractCollection->paginate($paginationCount, ['*'], 'p1');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter is for getting specific columns along with pagination. You could specify an array of strings representing column names.

In this case ['*'] represents all columns, which is default behaviour.